# Which future tense is better?

Tags: future-tense

> Did you know that Julia is having a baby? She ... (make) a great mother, I’ve no doubts.

Should it be **will** or **is going to**? And why exactly?

Comment: (In your *exact* case, few if any native speakers would see any difference in meaning between the two future tense forms.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me improve the already stated answer by @Astralbee

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work)

> Be going to or will?
>
> **Will is often used in a similar way to be going
>   to**. Will is used when we are talking about something with absolute
>   certainty. Be going to is used when we want to emphasise our decision
>   or the evidence in the present

More info: (1) [be going to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work) - (2) [will](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/will)

Both can be used in predictions. In your context, use **will** if *you want to express it with absolute certainty*, if you want to *exhibit complete confidence*; otherwise use **be going to**.

Answer (score 1):

They both convey pretty much the same meaning. I would happily use either. If I were to examine them in minute detail I would say:

> She will make a great mother

I think this is sounds the most certain - that you believe she already possess the qualities of a great mother.

> She is going to be a great mother

This *could* be interpreted to mean that she will *become* a great mother, therefore she may not yet possess all the qualities needed. But really, you'd have to be extremely paranoid to extract that meaning from it.